# Is It acceptable to write the First Letter of Each Word with upper case in CV?

Tags: resume

Is It acceptable to Write the First Letter of Each Word with Upper Case in CV?

E.g.: Determination to Achieve the Prefixed Goals (e.g. Learning Extracurricular Software to Improve My Professional Training)

Comment: What's possible is not always correct.

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace :) While it's clearly possible technically, it would be nice if you can mention your reasoning behind wanting to write in this manner.

Comment: As a recruiter this seems like a Transparent Attempt to Make your Resume Seem More Important. It's annoying.

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP asked if something is possible (acceptable) or not - isn't that a generic trend of q's we see here in TWP?

Comment: Changing the question from "possible" to "acceptable" is a big change. My answer was an answer to the original question. I didn't get into the possible consequences until after I had dealt with the "possible" issue by describing how to do it using a free editor.

Answer (score 11):

It is certainly possible, and many word processors automate it. For example, in OpenOffice, select that entire text and go to Format->Change Case->Capitalize Every Word. If you want to not capitalize certain words you would need to format those words individually.

However, there seems little point in formatting a CV in a way that would practically guarantee rejection of any application to which it was attached. It would be less work to just not file the applications, unless, as suggested in a comment, the objective is to nominally file applications without being offered a job.

Comment: _"..in a way that would practically guarantee rejection of any application to which it was attached"_ I fully agree but I'll go far out and speculate that maybe that's exactly what someone might want to achieve (i.E. when being on unemployment-support where one of the requirements would be to send out X-amount of applications each week/month and that someone doesn't feel like getting a new job too soon..).

Comment: Good point @iLuvLogix. I have edited the answer to include that possibility.

Answer (score 5):

#### No, don't do that.

Just because you *can* do something does not mean you *should*  do it.

Writing that way will seriously hurt eyes (read as, readability) thereby lessening your chances. Refrain from that idea.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this but I believe the question you want to ask is if you *should*.

Generally speaking, I would leave non-standard captalisation (all lowercase, ALL UPPERCASE, Titleised Formatting (Which Is What You Speak Of), you get the idea) to stylised headers only. [The Friggeri LaTeX CV template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv) is a good example of how to do this well.